# Graph as adjacency list performance

Tags: scala

I've implemented an adjacency list as `Array[List[Int]]` and basic graph creation routine goes like this

```
  val edges : List[(Int, Int)] = ... 
  val adj = Array.fill(v)(List.empty[Int])
  edges foreach { case(t, h) => adj(t) = h::adj(t) }
```

This implementation works approximately four times slower (tested with 5 million edges) than Java implementation based on `ArrayList<Integer>[]`. In Java edges are initially stored as `ArrayList<int[]>`. Any ideas on how to make Scala version faster?

Comment: If performance is the overriding factor, use two arrays. The pairs are formed by the entries in each of the arrays at a given index.

Comment: Could you provide complete both Java and Scala programs that can be run?

Answer (score 0):

For an initial collection of edges,

```
scala> val edges : List[(Int,Int)] = List((1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4))
e: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4))
```

consider this rearrangement,

```
scala> val adj = edges.groupBy{_._1}.map { case (k,v) => (k, v.map {_._2}) }
res21: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(2 -> List(3, 4), 1 -> List(2, 3, 4), 3 -> List(4))
```

Perhaps the use of the `par` method, which delivers a parallel implementation of a given collection and its associated methods,

```
scala> val adj = edges.par.groupBy{_._1}.map { case (k,v) => (k, v.map {_._2}) }
```

may improve the efficiency especially for large collections, such as for the original 5 million edges.